# adding a pre owned macbook to support list

Tags: hardware, macbook-pro, apple-id

I recently bought a store return macbook pro 15 retina, in perfect condition on eBay and Apple's 1 year warranty has not expired on it.

Now I want to addd it to my list of Apple products for support. "It" asks me for the original purchase date.

What can I do to add it to my name / apple ID?

Answer (score 1):

You'll most likely need to contact Apple to do this. Give 'em a call at 1-800-APL-CARE (1-800-275-2273) or use the [Express Lane](https://expresslane.apple.com/GetproductgroupList.action) to speed up the process a bit.